# Updating Chromium requires installation of untrusted packages

Tags: package-management, updates, chromium

I can't update my Ubuntu cause it says:

> Requires installation of untrusted packages
>
> The action would require the installation of packages from not
>   authenticated sources.
>
> chromium-browser chromium-browser-l10n chromium-codecs-ffmpeg

Why is that? I never changed anything and it always used to work fine.

Answer (score 2):

If you haven't installed any PPA's for Chromium, press the Reload button in the package manager (the command line equivalent is `sudo apt-get update`). If the problem persists, wait a day before retrying. The mirror is possibly not completely updated yet or a proxy is caching the contents.

Answer (score -1):

Try:

sudo add-apt-repository ppa:chromium-daily/ppa

That should authenticate your chromium packages and let you download the updates, etc.

Comment: The chromium-daily/ppa PPA contains a version that is updated every day from the development code which may be unstable. Do not recommend it for the average user.

Comment: Ok thanks for the info.  So you are saying that no ppa is necessary at all, and the problem will go away?  I had the problem too...

Comment: If you want a more recent version of Chromium, use `ppa:chromium-daily/stable`, but for normal usage, you do not need a PPA for it. Issues like these will go away in a short time.

Comment: Thanks so much, its really helpful to me and probably others. I am signing up to work with this community :-)